# JSON without keynames to ul li tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html

I've got JSON

```
data = {
  "408": "NameSurname1",
  "415": "NameSurname2"
}
```

How i can parse it with jQuery to

```
<ol>
   <li>
      <p>408</p> , <p>NameSurname1</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p>415</p> , <p>NameSurname2</p>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can describe _"without keynames"_ ?

Comment: Did any of the answers work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `for` in order to loop through the object and append the `li` elements

```js
data = {
  "408": "NameSurname1",
  "415": "NameSurname2"
}

for (i in data) {
   $('ol').append('<li><p>' + i + '</p><p>' + data[i] + '</p></li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way in my opinion is:

```
    var stringBuilder = "";
    for (var key in data) {
      stringBuilder += "<li><p>" + key + "</p>, <p>" + data[key] + "</p></li>";
    }
    $('yourOL').html(stringBuilder);
```